# How to save data table in Orange3

Tags: orange

I've setup a workflow in Orange3 and have tested some models. Now, I have the results in a Data table widget and I'm wondering if there is a way in which I can save the output of said widget?

I've tried using the Save data widget to no avail. Is there any other way?
I'm on a Mac, version 3.22.0, and I've experienced the same on a Windows machine.

Comment: Please detail your problem with “save data”. That’s the way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a kind of redundancy in the workflow. Please see the image below:

[image]